unable to set alias for search engine in Firefox
Firefox v 125.2 (beta )
Ubuntu 24.4
In Chrome browser, we can add search alias or sortcut and use it

but not able to find  similar feature  in Firefox in Ubuntu. someone suggest how to ad the alias of a website search term .
as per the Firefox official document it say double click on Keyword column  but there is no click working on it.
is there any developer flag need to enable to add search alias in Firefox?


Double click on the value itself i.e @google for example and then you should be able to enter text and change the value.

able to edit but  now where to set keyword? https://github.com adding directly , I want to open it with some sort of alias like gh? where do I write the alias in that field? @Raffa

You'll need to add it first … See https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/add-or-remove-search-engine-firefox … And then once it’s in that list, you can edit it and add a keyword infront of it.
